# Is there a way to see if a cell gets used in a formula and mark it with conditional formatting

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have set up and inventory sheet that uses part numbers as references, there is a dated *log out* sheet that goes into the formula on the current inventory sheet when it matches a part number.

Due to human error and mistake in entering part numbers, I would like to know if the value being logged out gets used, perhaps with a green check or light if used and red X or light if it's not used.

So I would need something that would do the following:

```
=IF cell A1 is used in any formula in Sheet1!B:B THEN mark with green check, IF cell A1 is not used in any formula in Sheet1!B:B THEN mark it with a red X
```

Comment: I have added VBA as this solution will require code.

Comment: The standard solutions for this require `NavigateArrows`, you can see examples for this in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895367/address-of-first-layer-of-precedent-cells-via-vba-in-excel. I don't think this will work well directly with a conditional formatting UDF

Answer (score 0):

[This microsoft help](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/display-the-relationships-between-formulas-and-cells-HP005201110.aspx) can get you very close to your requirement.

Comment: Not really. The question wanted to to conditional format cells used elsehwere, not trace dependents

Answer (score 0):

This code:

- tests each cell in A1:A10 of the first sheet as to whether there is a direct dependency to the second worksheet (further refinement would be needed to test if an intermediate reference on further sheets(s) was present)
- colours these cells red if there is a dependent on sheet2, else the interior format is cleared

**Set Region to be tested**

```
    Sub test()
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Set rng1 = Sheets(1).[a1:a10]
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each rng2 In rng1.Cells
    If oneCellsDependents(rng2) Then
    rng2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    Else
    rng2.Interior.Color = xlNone
    End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

**Dependent finder**

```
  Function oneCellsDependents(rng1 As Range) As Boolean
 ' written by Bill Manville
 ' With edits from PaulS
 ' this procedure  finds the  cells which are the direct precedents of the active cell
Dim rLast As Range, iLinkNum As Long, iArrowNum As Long
Dim bNewArrow As Boolean
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
rng1.ShowDependents
Set rLast = rng1
iArrowNum = 1
iLinkNum = 1
bNewArrow = True
Do
If oneCellsDependents Then Exit Do
    Do
        Application.Goto rLast
        On Error Resume Next
        rng1.NavigateArrow TowardPrecedent:=False, ArrowNumber:=iArrowNum, LinkNumber:=iLinkNum
        If Err.Number > 0 Then Exit Do
        On Error GoTo 0
        If rLast.Address(external:=True) = ActiveCell.Address(external:=True) Then Exit Do
        bNewArrow = False
                   If ActiveCell.Parent.Name = Sheets(2).Name Then
            oneCellsDependents = True
               Exit Do
        End If
        iLinkNum = iLinkNum + 1 ' try another  link
    Loop
    If bNewArrow Then Exit Do
    iLinkNum = 1
    bNewArrow = True
    iArrowNum = iArrowNum + 1 'try another arrow
Loop
rLast.Parent.ClearArrows
Application.Goto rLast
End Function
```