# Follow VLOOKUP and references in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

**Situation:**

I have a Excel workbook with many worksheets.
Some cells inside the workbook reference another Excel file (called `MasterData`) over a `vlookup`.

Some cells inside one worksheet (call it `Worksheet A`) reference other cells of another worksheet (call it `Worksheet B`). And the cells in `Worksheet B` reference `MasterData`.

In a third worksheet `Worksheet C` some cells reference `MasterData` directly.

My **Task** is, to find the dependency structure.
So for the above example it should give:

```
Worksheet A -> Worksheet B -> MasterData
Worksheet C -> MasterData
```

And of course for higher levels of linking (e.g `Worksheet D` -> `Worksheet E` -> `Worksheet F` -> `MasterData`

**What I've done so far:**

I am iterating over all worksheets and then over the cells of a worksheet. Inside the iteration I test if the cell has a formula and if the formula contains `MasterData` I know that this worksheet references `MasterData`.

So I already got the first level.

**Problem:**

Now I have cells like: (let's say I am in `Worksheet1` in cell `B2`)

```
=Worksheet2!A1
```

And the cell `A1` in `Worksheet2` looks like:

```
='X:\[MasterData.xslm]FZE'!A8
```

So when I process the cell `Worksheet1!B2` I would like to follow the reference to `Worksheet2!A1` and then see that this references `MasterData`.
*How can I achieve that?*

**Appendix**

I provide the code I've written so far. But it contains more than what I explained (it looks for the concrete worksheet in `MasterData`).

```
Sub Verknuepfungen_zwischen_Sheets_und_Masterdata()

' Zeigt auf, mit welchem Sheet aus der Masterdata ein Sheet der Planung verknüpft ist

Dim referenceToMaster As String
referenceToMaster = "MASTERDATA-Sep2014.xlsm]"

' schreibe Ausgabe in Analyse-Blatt
Dim analysisSheet As Worksheet
'  finde dazu ein eventuell vorhandenes Analyse-Blatt
If (SheetExists("Analyse-Blatt")) Then
    Set analysisSheet = sheets("Analyse-Blatt")
Else
    Set analysisSheet = sheets.Add(before:=sheets(1))
    analysisSheet.Name = "Analyse-Blatt"
End If

worksheetCount = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

currentRowIndex = 1
' Nun gehe jedes WorkSheet durch
Dim sheetsInMaster As Collection
Dim currentSheet As Worksheet
For c = 2 To worksheetCount
    Set currentSheet = sheets(c)
    ' nur sichtbare durchschauen
    If currentSheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
        ' nur die durchschauen, welche nicht schon Analyse-Blätter sind
        If (InStr(currentSheet.Name, "Formeln_") = 0) Then
            Set sheetsInMaster = New Collection
            Set r1 = currentSheet.Range("a1", currentSheet.Range("a1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
            For Each cell In r1.Cells
                ' schaue ob die Zelle eine Formel enthält
                If cell.HasFormula Then
                    ' schaue ob Formel eine Verweis auf die Masterplanung enthält
                    If InStr(cell.formula, referenceToMaster) > 0 Then
                        ' füge den Bereich in der Masterplanung den sheetsInMaster hinzu
                        AddMasterSheets cell.formula, sheetsInMaster
                    End If
                End If
            Next cell

            ' Ausgabe in Analyse-Blatt
            If sheetsInMaster.Count > 0 Then
                analysisSheet.Cells(currentRowIndex, 1) = currentSheet.Name
                For Each sheetInMaster In sheetsInMaster
                    analysisSheet.Cells(currentRowIndex, 2) = sheetInMaster
                    currentRowIndex = currentRowIndex + 1
                Next sheetInMaster
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next c

End Sub

Sub AddMasterSheets(ByVal formula As String, sheetsInMaster As Collection)
    ' Fügt der Collection "sheetsInMaster" die Namen der Arbeitsblätter der Masterplanung hinzu,
    ' auf welche in der "formula" verwiesen wird
    Dim referenceToMaster As String
    referenceToMaster = "MASTERDATA-Sep2014.xlsm]"

    Dim currentIndexOfReferenceToMaster As Integer
    Dim currentIndexOfPrime As Integer
    currentIndexOfReferenceToMaster = InStr(formula, referenceToMaster)
    Do While currentIndexOfReferenceToMaster <> 0
        currentIndexOfPrime = InStr(currentIndexOfReferenceToMaster, formula, "'")
        currentStart = currentIndexOfReferenceToMaster + Len(referenceToMaster)
        sheetInMaster = Mid(formula, currentStart, currentIndexOfPrime - currentStart)
        On Error Resume Next
            sheetsInMaster.Add sheetInMaster, CStr(sheetInMaster)
        On Error GoTo 0

        currentIndexOfReferenceToMaster = InStr(currentIndexOfPrime, formula, referenceToMaster)
    Loop

End Sub

Function SheetExists(sheetName As String) As Boolean
' Gibt zurück, ob ein Arbeitsblatt mit dem Namen existiert
  SheetExists = False
  For Each ws In Worksheets
    If sheetName = ws.Name Then
      SheetExists = True
      Exit Function
    End If
  Next ws
End Function
```

If you try this code on a Workbook with two worksheets called "PlanningA" and "PlanningB", where the cells in "PlanningA" are:

```
A1: =SVERWEIS($E4;'X:\[MASTERDATA-Sep2014.xlsm]Departments'!$G:$CF;AF$1238;FALSCH)

A2: =AF4*'X:\[MASTERDATA-Sep2014.xlsm]Stammdaten'!AG$2*('X:\[MASTERDATA-Sep2014.xlsm]Stammdaten'!AG$15+'X:\[MASTERDATA-Sep2014.xlsm]Stammdaten'!AG$19)/60+(AF11*AF4)

A3: =SVERWEIS($D4;'X:\[MASTERDATA-Sep2014.xlsm]Stammdaten'!$E$262:$CE$337;AF$1239;FALSCH)*8*AF4

A4: =SVERWEIS($E4;'X:\[MASTERDATA-Sep2014.xlsm]Machinery'!$G:$CF;AF$1238;FALSCH)
```

And in "PlanningB":

```
A1: =WENNFEHLER(SVERWEIS($E10;Werkebereich;BE$10000;FALSCH)*WVERWEIS($F10;'X:\[MASTERDATA-Sep2014.xlsm]FZE'!$3:$520;Montage!$D10-2;FALSCH);0)+WENNFEHLER(SVERWEIS($E10;Kitbereich;BE$10000;FALSCH)*WVERWEIS($F10;'X:\[MASTERDATA-Sep2014.xlsm]FZE'!$3:$520;Montage!$D10-2;FALSCH);0)

A2: =SVERWEIS($E4;'X:\[MASTERDATA-Sep2014.xlsm]LKZ-Part'!$G:$CF;AF$1238;FALSCH)
```

You will get a new worksheet called "Analyse-Blatt" which should look like:

```
 |A         |B
1|PlanningA |Departments
2|          |Stammdaten
3|          |Machinery
4|PlanningB |FZE
5|          |LKZ-Part
```

This is the first level, so I know that the worksheet `PlanningA` references the worksheet `Departments` in `MasterData`. But as you can see, the cell `A1` in `PlanningB` has a VLookUp to `Werkebereich`. And the referenced cells in `Werkebereich` have their own dependency to the sheet `Employees` in `Masterdata`. So what I am looking for is a table like:

```
 |A         |B           |C
1|PlanningA |Departments |
2|          |Stammdaten  |
3|          |Machinery   |
4|PlanningB |Werkebreich | Employees
5|          |FZE         |
6|          |LKZ-Part    |
```

I hope I gave enough information, to understand at what point I am, and to give me a hint to the solution of the problem:

*How can I follow references like VLOOKUP in VBA?*

Comment: Interesting question. This is a rather tricky task that involves parsing and off-sheet cell references (which NavigateArrows can do). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895367/address-of-first-layer-of-precedent-cells-via-vba-in-excel

Answer (score 1):

Will this work for you?

My test workbook has five worksheets. Starting on `Sheet1!A1`, each `A1` cell is chained to the `A1` cell on the next sheet. On `Sheet5!A1` there is simply a value. So the code below just checks to see if the formula associated with the given cell is a reference, then follows it until the end and returns a string with the whole chain. (You can replace this string with an array, or a comma-delimited string, or whatever you need.) In the test sub below, cell `Sheet1!A2` just has a simple value (so the `Formula` is blank).

```
Option Explicit

Private cellRefChain As String

Sub test()
    Debug.Print ListCellReferenceChain(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2"), 0)
    Debug.Print ListCellReferenceChain(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2"), 0)
End Sub

Function ListCellReferenceChain(startingCell As Range, level As Integer) As String
    Dim thisCellReference As String
    Dim destSheet As String
    If level = 0 Then
        cellRefChain = startingCell.Parent.Name & "!" & Replace(startingCell.Address, "$", "")
    End If
    destSheet = IsReference(startingCell.Formula)
    If Len(destSheet) > 0 Then
        thisCellReference = Right(startingCell.Formula, Len(startingCell.Formula) - 1)
        cellRefChain = cellRefChain & " --> " & thisCellReference
        level = level + 1
        ListCellReferenceChain Range(thisCellReference), level
    Else
        cellRefChain = cellRefChain & ".Value = " & startingCell.Value
    End If
    ListCellReferenceChain = cellRefChain
End Function

Function IsReference(cellFormula As String) As String
    Dim destinationSheet As String
    Dim pos1 As Integer
    destinationSheet = ""
    pos1 = InStr(1, cellFormula, "!", vbTextCompare)
    If pos1 > 0 Then
        destinationSheet = Mid(cellFormula, 2, pos1 - 2)
    End If
    IsReference = destinationSheet
End Function
```

The output is

```
Sheet1!A2.Value = LastName
Sheet1!A1 --> Sheet2!A1 --> Sheet3!A1 --> Sheet4!A1 --> Sheet5!A1.Value = 123
```

Comment: I didn't try your code yet, but as far as I can see, you resolve the reference by means of string-calculation. This is okay for simple references, but it doesn't work for `VLOOKUP`. One main objective was to avoid implementing the referencing logic of excel by myself, rather than reusing it. I thought there must be a way in VBA which lets me resolve functions with references...

Comment: Very true, my method only handles simple off-sheet cell references. I searched around for something like `VLOOKUP.ADDRESS`, and nothing exists in Excel for that. It's not impossible to write a routine to convert the `VLOOKUP` parameters into an `INDEX-MATCH` formula. Where my method **really** breaks down is if you have some complicated formula in a cell, such as `=IF(AND(SourceTable[@Field1]="Value1",SourceTable[@Field2]="Value2"),"Result1",IF(SourceTable[@Field2]="Value3","Result2","NotFound"))`. Your only real relief is the *Trace Precedents* function on the *Formulas* ribbon.

Comment: But the *Trace Precedents* doesn't create the table with the dependencies. And I have far too many fields, to do this by hand...

Comment: I started to expand my answer and realized (as you probably did) that the VBA code will eventually have to handle all the indirections and evaluations that Excel has built-in. This is clearly way too much work. I found an add-in that looks promising (with a 15-day free trial) that may get you what you want: [Dependency Author](http://www.spreadsheettools.com/da/product.asp). (NOTE: I have nothing to do with this product, I just stumbled across it in my research online.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have Office 365, or Office Professional Plus 2013, there is an awesome feature called Spreadsheet Inquire, which does exactly what you are looking for and will print it out in a nice web diagram. More info - see here: [What you can do with Spreadsheet Inquire](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/What-you-can-do-with-Spreadsheet-Inquire-ebaf3d62-2af5-4cb1-af7d-e958cc5fad42)

Professional Plus 2013 (which our company has a license to) has more programs like Spreadsheet Compare (which we use to diff excel files) that are nice.