# Evaluate formula references, but keep formula structure

Tags: vba, excel, cell-formatting

Is it possible in Excel to evaluate the references in a formula but keep the formula structure? e.g. if A1 = 5 and B1 = 10

=(A1+B1)/B1

would become

=(5+10)/10

in the cell, but keep the all the formula structure (i.e. = + /), rather than evaluate to 1.5.

Comment: It depends. As long as the references are single cell and on the same sheet as the formula, you can do it using the `Precedents` collection. Otherwise, you're basically looking at building a formula parser, which is not a trivial exercise.

Comment: I actually wrote a VBA script that will go through a formula that is written out with all the variables, and then go through the list of variables beneath the formula, and substitute the value in the cell to the right of the variables.  Then it will turn around and evaluate the formula. Its not all that hard as long as you are aware of how you need to write the formula

Comment: Could you just have the cell show `="("&A1&"+"&B1&")/"&B1`?

Comment: it basically boils down to identifying the cell with the formula, the range of the variables and their values and then looping through each variable and performing a substitute.

Comment: @BruceWayne that would get very cumbersome depending on how often the formula is changing or how complex the formula gets.  But still a valid point!

Comment: @ForwardEd If you can constrain the types of formula you can use, then yes, it may be relatively straightforward.

Comment: I am making the assumption he is only using basic math operators available to excel. ()*/+-^ and maybe the occasional built in basic functions like sqrt(), abs(), Pi().  and that his variables do not include those function names or parts of them.  No integration, factorials !, derivatives, or complex numbers.  That would need to be sent to a math prg not excel

Comment: @ForwardEd Then why not post the code for him to see if it helps? :)

Comment: Because it is on a work spreadsheet and today is a holiday so I am not in th office.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got some *almost* working code you could play around with.  It will work as long as individual cells are in the formula - so it won't work with `A1:C1` but will with `A1,B1,C1` - so no VLOOKUPS, or MATCH.  Just simple formula.

The main part of the code is credited to Bill Manville.
There's a Stackoverflow link:  [Address of first layer of precedent cells via VBA in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895367/address-of-first-layer-of-precedent-cells-via-vba-in-excel)  and

A couple of links to the original code:
http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?19348-Solved-Splitting-all-addresses-in-a-formula&p=142863#post142863
http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=17028

The code will place the formula with values in a comment in the cell:

```
Public Sub ReplaceWithValues()
    ' From original code written by Bill Manville for FindPrecedents.

    Dim rLast As Range, iLinkNum As Integer, iArrowNum As Integer
    Dim bNewArrow As Boolean
    Dim sTmpFormula As String

    ActiveCell.ShowPrecedents
    Set rLast = ActiveCell
    iArrowNum = 1
    iLinkNum = 1
    bNewArrow = True

    'Get an absolute reference version of the formula.
    sTmpFormula = Application.ConvertFormula _
                    (Formula:=ActiveCell.Formula, _
                     fromReferenceStyle:=xlA1, _
                     toReferenceStyle:=xlA1, _
                     toAbsolute:=xlAbsolute)

    Do
        Do
            Application.Goto rLast
            On Error Resume Next
            ActiveCell.NavigateArrow TowardPrecedent:=True, ArrowNumber:=iArrowNum, LinkNumber:=iLinkNum
            On Error GoTo 0
            If rLast.Address(external:=True) = ActiveCell.Address(external:=True) Then Exit Do
            bNewArrow = False
            If rLast.Worksheet.Parent.Name = ActiveCell.Worksheet.Parent.Name Then
                'Formula precedent is in same workbook.
                If rLast.Worksheet.Name = ActiveCell.Parent.Name Then
                    'Formula precedent is on the same sheet as formula.
                    sTmpFormula = Replace(sTmpFormula, Selection.Address(external:=True), Selection.Value)
                    sTmpFormula = Replace(sTmpFormula, Selection.Address, Selection.Value)
                Else
                    'Formula precedent is in same workbook, but different sheet.
                    If InStr(Selection.Parent.Name, " ") > 0 Then
                        'If the sheet name contains a space the reference will have ' at either end.
                        sTmpFormula = Replace(sTmpFormula, "'[" & Selection.Parent.Parent.Name & "]" & _
                            Selection.Parent.Name & "'!" & Selection.Address, Selection.Value)
                    Else
                        sTmpFormula = Replace(sTmpFormula, "[" & Selection.Parent.Parent.Name & "]" & _
                            Selection.Parent.Name & "!" & Selection.Address, Selection.Value)
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                sTmpFormula = Replace(sTmpFormula, Selection.Address(external:=True), Evaluate(Selection.Address(external:=True)))
            End If
            iLinkNum = iLinkNum + 1  ' try another link
        Loop
        If bNewArrow Then Exit Do
        iLinkNum = 1
        bNewArrow = True
        iArrowNum = iArrowNum + 1  'try another arrow
    Loop
    rLast.Parent.ClearArrows
    Application.Goto rLast
    rLast.AddComment
    rLast.Comment.Text Text:=sTmpFormula
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. I added a loop (`Dim c As Range; For Each c In Selection; c.Select; ...; Next`, and changed the third and fourth from last lines from adding a comment to replacing the values (i.e. to `rLast.FormulaR1C1 = sTmpFormula`). This also worked with named ranges referencing a different sheet.