# VBA code that goes to referenced cell

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I am trying to write a macro that goes to the referenced cell in a formula. So for example, if we have the following formula:

```
=IF(Sheet2!C3="","",Sheet2!C3)
```

I want the macro to take me to Sheet2 C3.
So I found this code thanks to you guys:

```
Dim rLast As Range, iLinkNum As Integer, iArrowNum As Integer
    Dim stMsg As String
    Dim bNewArrow As Boolean
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveCell.ShowPrecedents
    Set rLast = ActiveCell
    iArrowNum = 1
    iLinkNum = 1
    bNewArrow = True
    Do
        Do
            Application.Goto rLast
            On Error Resume Next
            ActiveCell.NavigateArrow TowardPrecedent:=True, ArrowNumber:=iArrowNum, LinkNumber:=iLinkNum
            If Err.Number > 0 Then Exit Do
            On Error GoTo 0
            If rLast.Address(external:=True) = ActiveCell.Address(external:=True) Then Exit Do
            bNewArrow = False
            If rLast.Worksheet.Parent.Name = ActiveCell.Worksheet.Parent.Name Then
                If rLast.Worksheet.Name = ActiveCell.Parent.Name Then
                     ' local
                    stMsg = stMsg & vbNewLine & Selection.Address
                Else
                    stMsg = stMsg & vbNewLine & "'" & Selection.Parent.Name & "'!" & Selection.Address
                End If
            Else
                 ' external
                stMsg = stMsg & vbNewLine & Selection.Address(external:=True)
            End If
            iLinkNum = iLinkNum + 1 ' try another  link
        Loop
        If bNewArrow Then Exit Do
        iLinkNum = 1
        bNewArrow = True
        iArrowNum = iArrowNum + 1 'try another arrow
    Loop
    rLast.Parent.ClearArrows
    Application.Goto rLast
    MsgBox "Precedents are" & stMsg

    Exit Sub

Range("stMsg").Select
Selection.Goto
```

And the variable contains the name of the cell. How can I make the macro go to it? The name format is 'Sheet2'!$C$3

Comment: What have you tried.  Stack Overflow is not a code for me or show me the code site.

Comment: Yes,I know and I am sorry. Just really do not know how to start.

Comment: You would need to parse the formula string: `Selection.Formula` using Left,Right, and/or Mid, with Instr to find certain characters like `!`

Comment: What if there's more than one referenced cell in a formula?  Which one does it go to?

Comment: Have a look at the link and search google for "FindPrecedents" and "Bill Manville".  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895367/address-of-first-layer-of-precedent-cells-via-vba-in-excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
With Range("'Sheet2'!$C$3")
    .Parent.Activate
    .Activate
End With
```

You can replace `'Sheet2'!$C$3` with the address you have found in your macro.

Comment: The variable is stMsg, but this does not send me to the Sheet2 cell C3.

Comment: It does send me :)

Answer (score 0):

For this case in specific:

```
Dim rng As Range  
Dim tmp As String  

tmp = Right(Selection.Formula, Len(Selection.Formula) - InStrRev(Selection.Formula, ","))  
Set rng = Range(Left(tmp, Len(tmp) - 1))
```