# Excel macro - finding cells that are used offsheet

Tags: vba, excel

I use the standard finance cell formatting where inputs are blue, cells that reference anything offsheet are green, and everything else is black.

All well and good - I was capable of developing macros that basically do what the GoTo -> constants -> numbers and GoTo -> formulas and then looks within the formula text for a "!" symbol.

However is there a way to select and highlight (say, in purple) all cells that are used offsheet, regardless of whether they are input as constants or formulas or whatever on the original sheet?

ie: I'd like to be able to quickly find and identify any cells that are used offsheet via macro.  I'm good at making macros in general, but just can't think up any functionality that would accomplish this.  Can anyone give me a hint to get me started in the right direction?

EDIT: What I have so far:

```
Sub Offsheet_Dependents()
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xCell As Range
Dim xTxt As String
On Error Resume Next
xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address
Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select the data range:", "EDI macro", xTxt, , , , , 8)
If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
' Need to modify the below for loop to only highlight cells where the reference is offsheet.  Currently higlights entire range.
' also need to add a cell.cleararrows command somewhere and have it work
For Each cell In xRg
    cell.ShowDependents
    Worksheet.cell.NavigateArrow TowardPrecedent:=False, ArrowNumber:=1, LinkNumber:=1
    If ActiveCell.Worksheet.Name <> Worksheet.cell.Worksheet.Name Then
        cell.Interior.Color = RGB(204, 192, 218)
    End If
    xRg.Select.ActiveSheet.ClearArrows
Next
End Sub
```

Another possibility, but the second macro doesn't successfully apply the first one across the range :( :

```
Sub Color_Dependents()
Dim rLast As Range, iLinkNum As Integer, iArrowNum As Integer
Dim stMsg As String
Dim bNewArrow As Boolean
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveCell.ShowDependents
Set rLast = ActiveCell
iArrowNum = 1
iLinkNum = 1
bNewArrow = True
Do
    Do
        Application.Goto rLast
        On Error Resume Next
        ActiveCell.NavigateArrow Towardprecedent:=False, ArrowNumber:=iArrowNum, LinkNumber:=iLinkNum
        If Err.Number > 0 Then Exit Do
        On Error GoTo 0
        If rLast.Address(External:=True) = ActiveCell.Address(External:=True) Then Exit Do
        bNewArrow = False
        If rLast.Worksheet.Parent.Name = ActiveCell.Worksheet.Parent.Name Then
            If rLast.Worksheet.Name = ActiveCell.Parent.Name Then
                 ' local
                stMsg = stMsg & vbNewLine & Selection.Address
            Else
                stMsg = stMsg & vbNewLine & "'" & Selection.Parent.Name & "'!" & Selection.Address
            End If
        Else
             ' external
            stMsg = stMsg & vbNewLine & Selection.Address(External:=True)
        End If
        iLinkNum = iLinkNum + 1 ' try another  link
    Loop
    If bNewArrow Then Exit Do
    iLinkNum = 1
    bNewArrow = True
    iArrowNum = iArrowNum + 1 'try another arrow
Loop
rLast.Parent.ClearArrows
Application.Goto rLast
If stMsg Like "*!*" Then
    ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(204, 192, 218)
End If
End Sub


Sub Purple_Range()
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xCell As Range
Dim xTxt As String
On Error Resume Next
xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address
Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select the data range:", "EDI macro", xTxt, , , , , 8)
Set xRg = Application.Union(xRg, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
For Each cell In xRg
    Call Color_Dependents
Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: @brettdj had a couple of links that sounds like they do exactly what you want:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895367/address-of-first-layer-of-precedent-cells-via-vba-in-excel

Comment: I'll check out the links now, but in the meantime, I've edited the OP to post what I've come up with so far... which doesn't work, but I suspect it's close.  As it stands now, code just highlights ALL selected cells as purple, not only the ones that pass the If criterion. Also it fails to then remove the arrows.

Comment: I'm still drawing a blank here. I read the links and tooled around more, but to no avail...

Comment: I did find a macro from @brettdj that I modified to be used on one cell at a time, and, if that cell has an off-sheet dependency, highlights it in purple.  This is a good start.

However, I'm having trouble applying this cell to a range and when i wrap it in a different macro and call it, it ceases to work.

Answer (score 2):

In Sub Purple_Range()

replace:

```
For Each cell In xRg
    Cell.Select 
Next cell
```

with:

```
For Each cell In xRg
    Cell.Select 
    Call Color_Dependents 
Next Cell
```

The reason why the second Macro was failing was because Color_Dependents() was updating the color of the current ActiveCell and Purple_Range() was cycling through the range with out updating the location of ActiveCell to make it current.

Otherwise the Macro was working fine.