# Parse formula to get the names of the sheets

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Is there an opportunity in Excel to parse the formula to get the names of the sheets that are in the formula?

There are formulas in which there are cells from different pages
[image: =Sheet2!A1+Sheet3!A1]

I would like to get a list of sheet names
[image: Sheet2 Sheet3]

Comment: Not sure whether to mark this as duplicate or not - afraid I can't see the image, so don't know how many of layers of formula you're trying to look through.  Check this link:  [Address of first layer of precedent cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895367/address-of-first-layer-of-precedent-cells-via-vba-in-excel)

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would be as below, it will take your formula into a variable and then loop through it to find all the Sheet names and write them into Row 2 (change as applicable):

```
Sub doit()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set the worksheet you are working with

    Valu = ws.Cells(1, 1).Formula
    'get the formula into a variable

    For i = 1 To Len(Valu) 'loop through the variable
        pos = InStr(Valu, "!") 'if ! found
        If pos > 0 Then
            ws.Cells(2, i).Value = Mid(Valu, 2, pos - 2) 'write into row 2 the Sheet name found
            Valu = Right(Valu, Len(Valu) - pos - 2)
            'replace the original variable to remove the first Sheet name found
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```